# convert date time to format ddd MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss

Tags: c#, datetime

In the below code snippet I'am passing string value "item.Date" to string "Date"
I wanted to convert it to this format `ddd MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss`.

converting to string and as well the above format was not going well i guess.

I tried using:

```
DateTime dateformatted =  DateTime.ParseExact(item.Date, "ddd dd MMM yyyy h:mm tt", null);
```

it showed error. Can anyone help

```
foreach (var item in data)
{
    model.Add(new MailDetailDTO
    {
        Attributes = item.Attribute1,
        Date = item.Date,
        From = item.SentFrom,
        FromOrg = item.OrganizationName,
        IsConfidential = item.IsConfidential,
        MailID = item.MailHeaderID,
    }
}
```

Comment: What error did you get? Are you sure there isn't a typo in your date format string? It doesn't look right to me.

Comment: What is the value in `item.Date` ? What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Your format and your `ParseExact` call don't match up.

Comment: Can you please confirm if you are getting the same error as this - `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.`?

Answer (score 0):

This is what the ParseExact API [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) on MSDN has to say :

> The format of the string representation **must match the specified**
>   **format exactly**.

This means that there is a certain mismatch in the format you have stored the date time value in `item.Date` string property and the custom date time format `ddd dd MMM yyyy h:mm tt` which you're passing as argument to `ParseExact` API.

Have a look at the below code snippet:

```
    private static void DateTimeForatError()
    {
        var item = "Sun 22-May-2016 3:52 AM";
        DateTime dateformatted = DateTime.ParseExact(item, "ddd dd MMM yyyy h:mm tt", null); //results in exception
    }
```

Date time string value present in item variable looks parseable but the next line results in `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.` error. That is because I'm using `-` hyphen as the delimiter for day, month and year while the custom format string `dd MMM yyyy` uses space . As long as there is even a single difference in the way I have stored date time string value in item variable which is not complying with the custom format string `ddd dd MMM yyyy h:mm tt` it will burst. The moment I make the value of item to `Sun 22 May 2016 3:52 AM` it succeeds. You just change the value of item.Date in the object of `MailDetailDTO` object to match it with the custom date time string format to get rid of the error **OR** change the custom date time format string that you are passing to the `PraseExact` API to match it with the format of date time value coming in `item.Date` from your back-end data.